# Closing balance of the previous day as an Opening balance of today

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am developing a database application for a small electronics business. I need a SQL query which takes the closing balance of previous day as an opening  balance of current day. I have following data tables

**Expensis**

```
ExpenseID   Date         Expense 

1           2019-03-01   2,000
2           2019-03-02   1,000
3           2019-03-03   500
```

**Income**

```
IncomeID    Date        Income

1         2019-03-01    10,000
2         2019-03-02    13,000
3         2019-03-03    10,000
```

**Required result**

```
Date        Opening Balance     Income      Expense    Closing Balance

2019-03-01      0               10,000      2,000       8,000
2019-03-02      8,000           13,000      1,000       20,000  
2019-03-03      20,000          10,000      5,00        29,500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum` aggregation function recursively ( `lag` window analytic function cannot be used for `sql server 2008` )

```
with Expensis( ExpenseID, Date, Expense ) as
(
 select  1, '2019-03-01', 2000 union all
 select  2, '2019-03-02', 1000 union all
 select  3, '2019-03-03', 500            
 ), Income( IncomeID, Date, Income ) as
     (
     select  1, '2019-03-01', 10000 union all
     select  2, '2019-03-02', 13000 union all
     select  3, '2019-03-03', 10000                 
    ), t as
    (
    select i.date, 
           i.income,
           e.expense,
           sum(i.income-e.expense) over (order by i.date) as closing_balance              
      from income i
      join expensis e on e.date = i.date
     )
     select date, 
            ( closing_balance - income + expense ) as opening_balance,
            income, expense, closing_balance
       from t;

date        opening balance income  expense closing balance
----------  --------------- ------  ------- ---------------
2019-03-01  0               10000   2000    8000
2019-03-02  8000            13000   1000    20000
2019-03-03  20000           10000   500     29500
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/NUT33827)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it
You have to valuate income and expenses differently

```
WITH INCOME AS
(
   SELECT '2018-01-05' AS DT, 200 AS INC, 1 AS TP
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '2018-01-06' AS DT, 300 AS INC,  1 AS TP
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '2018-01-07' AS DT, 400 AS INC,  1 AS TP
)

, EXPENSES AS
(
   SELECT '2018-01-05' AS DT, -100 AS EXPS, 2 AS TP
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '2018-01-06' AS DT, -500 AS EXPS, 2 AS TP
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '2018-01-07' AS DT, -30 AS EXPS, 2 AS TP
)

, UN AS
(
   SELECT * FROM INCOME
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM EXPENSES
)

SELECT *, [1]+[2] AS END_BALANCE FROM UN

PIVOT
(
   SUM(INC)
   FOR TP IN ([1],[2])          
)   AS P
```